# Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at name. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Tags: ios, swift, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All, I am having some trouble with a Firebase driven app I am working on. The issue came about after upgrading my xCode to version 8. I have done some extensive research on this and gone through a few Stackoverflow topics trying to solve this, as it seems to be a very common error. I've gathered it is probably something super obvious that I am missing, excuse my stupidity.

This is the error I am receiving.

> Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at name. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

This is my section of code it's occuring in I believe.

```
    func saveUser(withUID uid: String, username: String, value: [String:   String?], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
         let values = ["/users/\(uid)": value, "/usernames/\(username)": uid] as [String: Any]
         root.updateChildValues(values) { (error, _) in
            completion(error)
        }
    }

    func updateUser(_ newValue: [String: String?]) {
        currentUser.updateChildValues(newValue)
    }

    // MARK: - Posts

    func createPost(_ _post: [String: String]) {

        let userUID = Auth.shared.currentUserUID
        let key = posts.childByAutoId().key

        var post = _post
        post["userUID"] = userUID

        // get current user's username
        currentUser.child("username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {     snapshot in
            if let username = snapshot.value as? String {
                post["username"] = username
                let values = [
                    "/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userUID)/\(key)": post
                ]
                self.root.updateChildValues(values)
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: What does your `post` look like..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in my code as well, just figured that out.  Make sure `values` is type of `[String : String]` instead of `[String : String?]`.